# How can I modify my shader code to make the background transparent?

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader

I'm trying to work with this shader, but I need a transparent background and it renders a black background. I realized that this is done within the fragmentShader, but I haven't figured out how to change it, and I don't even know if it's possible. Would anyone with experience in shaders know how to tell me?

fragment shader:

```c
uniform vec3 iResolution;
uniform float iTime;
varying vec2 v_position;
// precision mediump float;

// #ifdef GL_ES
// #ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
//   precision highp float;
// #else
//   precision mediump float;
// #endif
// #endif
// #ifdef GL_ES
// #ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
  precision highp float;
// #else
  // precision mediump float;
// #endif
// #endif

#define PI 3.14
#define TWO_PI 6.28

#define TIMESCALE 0.5

#define BLUR_STRENGTH 2.0
#define BLUR_RANGE 2.7

// #define UI_COLOR vec4(0.5, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0)
#define UI_COLOR vec4(0.125, 0.455, 0.804, 1.0)

float hash12(vec2 x)
{
  return fract(sin(dot(x, vec2(43.5287, 41.12871))) * 523.582);
}

vec2 hash21(float x)
{
  return fract(sin(x * vec2(24.0181, 52.1984)) * 5081.4972);
}

float hash11(float x)
{
  return fract(sin(x * 42.146291) * 4215.4827);
}

vec2 hash22(vec2 x)
{
  return fract(sin(x * mat2x2(24.4372, 12.47864, 32.3874, 29.4873)) * 4762.832);
}

mat2x2 rotationMatrix(in float angle)
{
  return mat2x2(-cos(angle), sin(angle), -sin(angle), -cos(angle));
}

//Blur function
vec4 blur(in sampler2D samplerTexture, in vec2 fragCoord, in vec2 resolution)
{
    vec2 uv = fragCoord / resolution;
    float blurStrength = distance(uv, vec2(0.5));
    blurStrength = pow(blurStrength, BLUR_RANGE) * (resolution.x / 100.0) * BLUR_STRENGTH;
    vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);
    vec2 pixelSize = vec2(1.0) / resolution;
    for (float x = -1.0; x <= 1.0; x += 1.0)
    {
      for (float y = -1.0; y <= 1.0; y += 1.0)
        {
            sum += texture(samplerTexture, uv + vec2(x, y) * pixelSize * blurStrength);
        }
    }

    return sum / 9.0;
}


float circle(in vec2 uv, in float radius, in float width)
{
    return smoothstep(width, width * 0.5, abs(radius - length(uv)));
}

float softCircle(in vec2 uv, in float radius, in float width)
{
    return smoothstep(width, 0.0, abs(radius - length(uv)));
}

float hardCircle(in vec2 uv, in float radius, in float width)
{
  return smoothstep(width, width * 0.99, abs(radius - length(uv)));
}

float dottedCircle(in vec2 uv, in float circleRadius, in float dotRadius, float dotsCount)
{
  float angle = atan(uv.y, uv.x);
  angle /= TWO_PI;
  angle += 0.5;
  angle = round(angle * dotsCount) / dotsCount;
  angle *= TWO_PI;
  //angle *= round(angle / TWO_PI * dotsCount) * TWO_PI;
  vec2 dotPoint = vec2(circleRadius, 0.0) * rotationMatrix(angle);
  return smoothstep(dotRadius, dotRadius * 0.99, distance(dotPoint, uv));

  return angle;
}

float circularSector(vec2 uv, in float radius, in float width, in float cutAngle)
{
    float angle = atan(uv.y, uv.x) + PI;
    float circ = circle(uv, radius, width);
    return circ * smoothstep(cutAngle, cutAngle - 0.001, abs(angle - cutAngle));
}

float cutSector(in vec2 uv, in float cutAngle, in float offset)
{
  float angle = atan(uv.y, uv.x) + PI + offset;
  angle = mod(angle, TWO_PI);
   return smoothstep(cutAngle, cutAngle - 0.0001, abs(angle - cutAngle));
}

float dashedCircle(vec2 uv, in float radius, in float width, in float density)
{
  float angle = atan(uv.y, uv.x) + PI;
  angle /= TWO_PI;
  angle = fract(angle * density);
  float circ = circle(uv, radius, width);
  return circ * smoothstep(0.1, 0.11, abs(angle - 0.5));
}

float dottedGrid(vec2 uv, in vec2 gridSpaces, float dotRadius)
{
  uv = mod(uv, gridSpaces) - gridSpaces * 0.5;
  return smoothstep(dotRadius, 0.0, abs(length(uv) - dotRadius));
}

float dottedGridWithinRadius(vec2 uv, in vec2 gridSpaces, float dotRadius, float radius)
{
    if (length(uv) > radius) {
        return 0.0; // 若超出给定半径则返回0.0，表示不生成点
    }

    uv = mod(uv, gridSpaces) - gridSpaces * 0.5;
    return smoothstep(dotRadius, 0.0, abs(length(uv) - dotRadius));
}

float lineGrid(vec2 uv, in vec2 gridSpaces, float lineWidth)
{
    uv = mod(uv, gridSpaces) - gridSpaces * 0.5;
    float verticalLines = smoothstep(lineWidth, lineWidth * 0.5, abs(uv.x - lineWidth));
    float horizontalLines = smoothstep(lineWidth, lineWidth * 0.5, abs(uv.y - lineWidth));
    return verticalLines + horizontalLines;
}

float writings(vec2 uv, in float linesCount, in float maxLen, in float height, in float hash)
{
    float mul =
        smoothstep(0.0, 0.01, uv.x)
        * smoothstep(0.0, 0.01, uv.y)
        * smoothstep(height, height - 0.001, uv.y);

    uv.y = clamp(uv.y, 0.0, height);
    uv.y *= linesCount;
    float len = hash11(floor(uv.y - linesCount) + hash) * maxLen;
    return smoothstep(len, len * 0.5, uv.x) * hash12(uv) * mul * fract(uv.y);
}

float writingsGrid(vec2 uv, in vec2 gridSpace, in float scale)
{
  uv /= gridSpace;
  vec2 floorUV = floor(uv);
  vec2 fractUV = fract(uv);

  fractUV -= hash22(floorUV) * (1.0 - (1.0 / scale)) * (sin(iTime * 0.6 * TIMESCALE + hash12(floorUV) * 12.0) * 0.5 + 0.5);
  fractUV *= scale;

  float writing = writings(fractUV, 10.0 * hash12(floorUV) + 5.0, 1.0, hash12(floorUV + 0.1) * 0.6, 1.0);

  return writing;
}


vec3 uvToCameraPlanePoint(in vec2 uv)
{
  // return vec3(uv.x, uv.y, 1.5 + sin(iTime * TIMESCALE * 0.3) * 0.2);
  return vec3(uv.x, uv.y, 1.5);
}

//xy - plane uv
//z - plane height
//w - distance to plane
vec4 raycastPlane(in vec3 rayOrigin, vec3 rayDirection, in float planeHeight)
{
  float distanceToPlane = abs(rayOrigin.y - planeHeight);
  rayDirection /= rayDirection.y;
  rayDirection *= distanceToPlane;
  vec3 hitPoint = rayOrigin + rayDirection;

  return vec4(hitPoint.x, hitPoint.z, hitPoint.y, length(rayDirection));
}


void main()
{
    // vec2 uv = (2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy - iResolution.xy) / iResolution.x;
    vec2 uv = (2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy - iResolution.xy) / iResolution.x;
    float time = iTime * TIMESCALE;
    // float angleTime = iTime * 0.5 * TIMESCALE;
    float angleTime = 0.0;

    float angleY = -time;
    float angleX = -0.75;
    float angleZ = 0.0;
    mat3 rotation =mat3(-cos(angleZ),  sin(angleZ), 0,
                           -sin(angleZ), -cos(angleZ), 0,
                           0, 0,  1)
        * mat3(1, 0, 0,
                           0, -cos(angleX),  sin(angleX),
                           0, -sin(angleX), -cos(angleX))
        * mat3(-cos(angleY),  0, sin(angleY),
                           0,  1, 0,
                           -sin(angleY), 0, -cos(angleY));

    vec3 cameraPosition = vec3(sin(time), -3.20, cos(time));
    vec3 castPlanePoint = uvToCameraPlanePoint(uv);
    castPlanePoint = castPlanePoint * rotation;
    castPlanePoint += cameraPosition;
    vec3 rayOrigin = vec3(cameraPosition);
    vec3 rayDirection = normalize(castPlanePoint - cameraPosition);

    vec4 hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -4.0);
    float dist = hitPoint.w;
    float fog = smoothstep(5.0, 0.0, dist);
    // float dots = dottedGrid(hitPoint.xy, vec2(0.03), 0.001);
    float dots = dottedGridWithinRadius(hitPoint.xy, vec2(0.03), 0.001,0.5);

    //dots += hardCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.3, 0.07 + 0.03 * sin(time * 0.6)) * cutSector(hitPoint.xy, 1.5 + cos(time * 0.4) * 2.0, time * 2.0) * 0.4;

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -4.02);
    float lines = lineGrid(hitPoint.xy, vec2(0.4), 0.001) * 0.5;
    lines += hardCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.12, 0.02 + 0.01 * -sin(time * 0.6 + 2.0)) * cutSector(hitPoint.xy, 1.5 + cos(time * 1.4) * 2.0, -time * 0.8) * 0.4;

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -3.98);
    float lines2 = lineGrid(hitPoint.xy + 0.14, vec2(0.8), 0.002) * 0.4;

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -3.97);
    float dotCircle = dottedCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.5, 0.003, 200.0) + dottedCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.5, 0.006, 20.0) * cutSector(hitPoint.xy, 2.3, time * 4.0);

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -3.9);
    float circle1 = circle(hitPoint.xy, 0.6, 0.003) * 0.4 + 0.4 * (dottedCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.61, 0.003, 300.0) + dottedCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.61, 0.006, 30.0)) * cutSector(hitPoint.xy, 1.0, -iTime * 0.1);

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -3.94);
    float circle2 = circle(hitPoint.xy, 0.45, 0.003) * 0.3 + 0.3 * dottedCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.46, 0.004, 250.0);

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -3.88);
    float circle3 = circle(hitPoint.xy, 0.42, 0.003) * 0.4 + dottedCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.42, 0.005, 20.0) * 0.8 * cutSector(hitPoint.xy, 1.0, time * 2.0);

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -3.8);
    float circle4 = dashedCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.38, 0.006, 10.0) * 0.8 * cutSector(hitPoint.xy, 1.0, -time * 0.6);
    circle4 += dashedCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.3, 0.0045, 2.5 + sin(time * 2.0)) * cutSector(hitPoint.xy, 2.0, time * 0.28) * 0.7;

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -3.84);
    float circle5 = circle(hitPoint.xy, 0.15, 0.003) * 0.4 + dottedCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.2, 0.003, 100.0) * 0.8 * cutSector(hitPoint.xy, 0.5, cos(time * 0.2) * 10.0);

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -3.8);
    circle5 += circle(hitPoint.xy, 0.1, 0.003) * 0.4 + dottedCircle(hitPoint.xy, 0.2, 0.003, 100.0) * 0.8 * cutSector(hitPoint.xy, 1.0, sin(time * 0.2 + 2.0) * 10.0);

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -4.0);
    float writingGrid = writingsGrid(hitPoint.xy + time * 0.02, vec2(0.6, 0.6), 6.0);

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -3.8);
    writingGrid += writingsGrid(hitPoint.xy - time * 0.02 + 20.0, vec2(1.0, 1.0), 6.0);

    hitPoint = raycastPlane(rayOrigin, rayDirection, -3.85);
    float circle6 = circle(hitPoint.xy, 0.05, 0.0025) * 0.6 * cutSector(hitPoint.xy, 2.5 + sin(time * 0.67) * 0.5, time * 2.0);

    float UIMerge =  dots + dotCircle + circle1 + circle2 + circle3 + circle4 + circle5 + circle6;

    vec4 color = UI_COLOR * UIMerge;

    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

vertex shader:

```c
varying vec2 v_position;
      void main() {
        v_position = vec2(position.x, position.y);
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);

      }
```

Comment: You cannot do this in the shader alone. You must activate the "blending" of the geometry with the background. To do this, you must set the corresponding attributes in the [ShaderMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShaderMaterial).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried setting `transparent=true` in `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial`. Although it displays a transparent background on most devices, there are still some devices showing a black background. So, I'm considering whether I should implement this transparent background in the shader. I'm not very familiar with shader code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that inside fragment.

You should play with `alpha` value in fragment, alpha is responsible for transparency.

```
float alpha = // adjust calculations according your fragment;
```

final

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(UI_COLOR.rgb * UIMerge, alpha);
```